# Callback object destroys itself while executing when replacing itself with new value

Tags: c++, algorithm, callback, control-flow, object-lifetime

Consider the following situation:

```
struct A {
    // `unique_function` is like std::function but does not
    // require its target to be Copyable, and is in turn
    // itself not Copyable either.
    unique_function<void()> callback = []{};

    void set_callback(unique_function<void()> new_callback) {
        callback = std::move(new_callback);
        callback();
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.set_callback([&, x = std::make_unique<int>(42)]{
        std::cout << "Ok at this point, *x = " << *x << ".\n";
        a.set_callback([]{}); // This destroys enclosing lambda
        // while is is being executed, thus messing things up.
        // Captures are not legal to access here.
    });
}
```

The intended semantics in this situation is to have all callbacks called when they are set, and have the last one set be stored within `callback` when the top `set_callback` returns.

Solutions I can see:

1. Replace `unique_function<void()>` with something Copyable, like `std::shared_ptr<unique_function<void()>>` or specialized `shared_function<void()>` and then call the copy:

   ```
   shared_function<void()> callback = []{};

   void set_callback(shared_function<void()> new_callback) {
       callback = std::move(new_callback);
       auto callback_copy = callback;
       callback_copy();
   }
   ```

   Drawbacks:

   1. Overhead or reference counting.
2. Have a list, and append callbacks to it before executing them. When top `set_callback` returns, `callbacks.back()` is the last callback set, and the rest can be erased. This requires an additional counter tracking current depth of `set_callback` calls.

   ```
   std::deque<unique_function<void()>> callbacks;
   std::size_t depth = 0;

   struct depth_controller {
       std::size_t& depth;
       depth_controller(std::size_t& d) : depth(d) { ++depth; }
       ~depth_controller() { --depth; }
   };

   void set_callback(shared_function<void()> new_callback) {
       callbacks.emplace_back(std::move(new_callback));
       {
           depth_controller dctl{depth};
           callbacks.back()();
       }
       if (depth > 0) { return; }
       callbacks.erase(callbacks.begin(),
                       std::prev(callbacks.end()));
   }
   ```

   Drawbacks:

   1. Overhead of callback list and depth counter.

Can we do better?

Comment: Can't you just keep the old callback around until the new one finishes executing? `auto old = std::move(callback); callback = std::move(new_callback); callback();` or simply: `swap(callback, new_callback); callback();`

Comment: @JonathanWakely it seems that I can, yes. Now I feel stupid.

Comment: Well it's not that obvious, but I've dealt with problems like this before.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, actually wait, no. If I do that then `a.set_callback(/* foo: */[&]{ a.set_callback(/* bar: */[]{}); /* at this point foo has been moved to local variable 'old' within preceding 'set_callback' call, and subsequently destroyed when 'set_callback' returned. */})`

Comment: Yes. You could return the old callback to the caller so the caller can keep it alive longer. But at some point you need to limit what you expect to work.